# 'Skip List' examples?

Tags: protocol, ledger

Has anyone used the 'Skip List' property on the ledger? If so, do you have an example / use case?

> Skip list: Hashes of ledgers in the past. Allows you to jump back in time in the ledger chain without walking back ledger by ledger. There are 4 ledger hashes stored in the skip list. Each slot contains the oldest ledger that is mod of either 50 5000 50000 or 500000 depending on index skipList[0] mod(50), skipList[1] mod(5000), etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skip list are designed to speed up ledger chain validation as they allow to jump in the chain by up to 500000 ledgers (that's about a month worth of ledgers).

Use case is that even from thin client you can verify that a ledger that you are observing is indeed connected to genesis (going back from that ledger) and/or connected to the latest ledger from consensus (you would need to walk back from the consensus ledger).